# Using equalizehist before CascadeClassifier::detectMultiscale

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, histogram, object-detection

I made a little research myself concerning the question that is it really neccessary to use equalizeHist before calling the detectMultiscale function. I trained my classifier with discrete AdaBoost.

If I'm not mistaken, the main purpose of rescaling the histogram is to increase the contrast of the image.

I checked the detection results with only one image, but with different contrast ratios. I almost grayed out completly the image, but I didn't observed too much difference. Actually the difference was marginally: Sometimes a false negative, sometimes a true positive popped out using the histogram equalizer. Maybe it was the image, but I observed that, when I started to lower the contrast, at the beginning mostly the false alerts started to disappear.

So my question briefly is that: Is it really neccessary to use equalizeHist before calling the detectMulticale.

Comment: Where did you get this impression of necessity?

Comment: I read that somewhere.